# Math biology proof by induction question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

I am stuck on this question:

Consider the delay-differential equation
$\frac{d}{
dt}x(t) = x(t − 1)$,
with $x(t) = 1$ for $t \in [−1, 0]$. The solution is given by
$x(t) = \sum^{n}_{0}{\frac{[t − (k − 1)]^k}{k!}}$
for $n − 1 \leq t \leq n$,
where $n$ is a non-negative integer.
Use proof by induction (i.e., method of steps) to find the solution

I have tried to use the sum of a geometric series on the series and then differentiating this and setting it equals to $x(t-1)$ also in the geometric series however when i tried to the basis case $k=1$ I ended up with $\frac{1-t^n}{t-1}=\frac{1+t^2(t-1)^n-nt^3(t-1)^{n-1}}{t^2}$ which I am unable to prove is true, can anyone see where I have gone wrong or suggest a better method of approach this?

-edited so that n is the upper limit

Comment: I think you're totally misreading the definition of $x(t)$.  It's not an infinite series; it's a piecewise-polynomial function, which adds one degree at each nonnegative integer.

Comment: So we rewrite $x(t)$ as $1+t+\frac{(t-1)^2}{2!}+\frac{(t-2)^3}{3!}+...+\frac{(t-(k-1)^k}{k!}$ would we then get $x(t-1)$ by subbing in $t-1$ where ever we see $t$?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  But I think you've also got the limits on your summation wrong.  You have $k$ as the index and the upper limit.  I think that upper limit is $n$, the same $n$ where $n-1 <t \leq n$.

Comment: Ok I have fixed the n in the upper limit as I had typed it in wrong and then I worked this out using your expansion and got $$x(t-1)=t+\frac{(t-2)^2}{2!}+\frac{(t-3)^}{3!}+...+\frac{(t-n)^n}{n!}$$ and then $$\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=t+\frac{(t-2)^2}{2!}+\frac{(t-3)^}{3!}+...+\frac{(t-(n-1))^n}{(n-1)!}$$ so is this what we need to use proof by induction on the prove that the last terms are the same for all n?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you might formulate the answer:  Let $x_n(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(t-(k-1))^k}{k!}$.  Then $x(t) = x_n(t)$ where $n - 1 < t \leq n$.  Just to be explicit,
$$
    x(t) = 
    \begin{cases}
        1   & \text{if $0 < x \leq 1$} \\
        1+t & \text{if $1 < x \leq 2$} \\
        1+t+\frac{1}{2}(t-1)^2 & \text{if $2 < x \leq 3$} \\
        1+t+\frac{1}{2}(t-1)^2 + \frac{1}{6}(t-2)^3 & \text{if $3 < x \leq 4$} \\
        \dots & \dots
    \end{cases}
$$

You need to show $x'(t) = x(t-1)$ for all $t \geq 0$.  On the interval $n-1 < t \leq n$, we have $x(t) = x_n(t)$ and $x(t-1) = x_{n-1}(t-1)$.  So it suffices to show that $x_n'(t) = x_{n-1}(t-1)$ for each $n$.

For this, I'm not even sure you need induction.  For
\begin{align*}
    x_n'(t) &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k(t-(k-1))^{k-1}}{k!}
             = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(t-(k-1))^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}
             = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(t-k)^{k}}{k!} \\
    x_{n-1}(t-1)
            &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{((t-1)-(k-1))^{k}}{k!}
             = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(t-k)^{k}}{k!}
\end{align*}